# Computer froze up

Tags: freeze

Why would my computer freeze up out of the blue? I have Apache Webserver w/php, and MySQL server installed. I am not sure exactly when it happened, but I was doing something on a wordpress site that I have installed, and it just waited and waited and waited. Then, all the folders on it that were open on my other computer closed, as though I had disconnected it. Then the skype account went offline. The computer was totally froze. I thought maybe it was someone on logmein, but disconnecting it from the network didn't do anything. I had to "crash" it (held in the power button till it shutdown). It started up normally then and the logs showed absolutely nothing wrong. And doing the same thing that I did when it froze didn't repeat the freeze. Any ideas, I never had this happen before.

**Computer:** Windows 2000 SP4

Comment: Hardware specs? OS?

Comment: Computers crash sometimes. If it happens repeatedly, I'd worry, but once?

Comment: what server software is installed? do you have an antivirus?

Comment: @ceejayoz - my computer doesn't crash without a good reason. I would worry if it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes it just happens. Some things you can do is check the logs in Event Viewer (which I assume is what you meant when you said you checked the logs) and even looking in scheduled tasks (Who knows? Something might've gotten scheduled that simply crashed it.)
Possibly look at the Device Manager to see if anything is awry there.

Really though, it was probably an occasional hiccup or you had the computer running far too long(funny how computers cam sometimes do that.) I'd put it out of mind unless it starts happening more, and  more frequently.

Answer (score 0):

If it happened just once then it could be just about anything.  Possibly even bad hardware.  If there's nothing in the system logs around the time that the crash happened then it is going to be really difficult to diagnose without it happening more frequently.

Answer (score -2):

There are many reasons that a computer can crash. Windows OS for instance have a nasty habit of using up system resources until it can't move any longer. Badly written programs can "forget" to give control back, filesystems can get full, and hardware can malfunction. Checking logs can help figure things out sometimes. One reason why I prefer the *nix philosophy of fail noisily and soon.

I noticed that you use Windows 2000 server. If you must use Windows, upgrading to the latest version might help. Of course, if it only froze once, you probably have nothing to worry about for now.

Comment: No, I don't have the server version, I have Windows 2000 Professional